# How do that scripts jquery working for content upload grom ajax?

Tags: jquery

Good day.

For example i have code:

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){alert("hello");})

<button id="button">Test</button>
```

if this code find on page all working, but if we upload button use ajax, jquery for `#button` not work and he work if i upload his only with button use ajax...

But i would be write all jquery scripts for page in a separate file...

***How make that script jquery work for element which we add in body page use jquery ?***

Comment: Don't show your working code, show your problematic code and explain what you need help with

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Comment: i have answer but i cannt add him 7 hourse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1 (direct):

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {...});
```

Case 2 (delegated):

```
$("body").on("click", "#button", function() {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

as @hjpotter92 pointed out, with ajax added content you can use delegation. So attach the havent handler to the container where you upload your button and specify a class for example to catch the right event.

```
$("#container").on("click", ".my-button", function() { alert("hello"); })
```